# How to wrap a non-OO module of functions into a moose class

Tags: moose

A few month ago I started to use Moose.

There are some non-OO modules I use simply made of related functions. I'd like to use these functions in Moose classes as methods. May be the simplest way doing it is like

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

package FuncPack;

sub func_1 {
    print "-> ", __PACKAGE__, "::func_1 called \n";
}

package FuncClass;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

sub func_1 {
    my $self = shift ;
    return FuncPack::func_1(@_);
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;


package main;

my $obj = FuncClass->new();    
$obj->func_1(); # shall call FuncPack::func_1
```

For one function it may be ok, but if you have a lot it's a repeating task and boring. 
Is there a more clever way to accomplish it ? May be there is something similar to MooseX::NonMoose or MooseX::InsideOut which are for extending non-Moose classes ?

Thanks for advice or hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moose typically doesn't deal with this, wrapping non-OO modules in an OO framework seems a bit odd. However if you have a list of the methods (or can generate one) you could do something like:

```
package FuncClass;
use Moose;

my @list = qw( func_1 func_2 func_3 ... );
for my $method in @list {
   __PACKAGE__->meta->add_method(
       $method => sub { my $s = shift; FuncPack::$method(@_)  
   });
}
```

You may be able to use something like `Package::Stash` to pull out the list of functions from `FuncPack`.

I'm wondering however why you would want to do this to begin with? Your `FuncClass` will be carrying absolutely no state, and really doesn't serve a purpose other than to add a layer of indirection.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for. My example is too simplified - just to make clear what I need. I did'nt touch the meta stuff by now. I think it's time for it ;-).